# Docker v1.12 can not change hostname by env variable $HOSTNAME

Tags: docker, hostname

With previous docker versions, the command of "hostname" and "echo $HOSTNAME" returned same thing, after I changed it by sending an env variable into the image.

Why I use this is that **I want to insert a new host into /etc/hosts by invoking hostname or $HOSTNAME. So my service/app inside this docker can get the 'real' IP address or the one I assigned, while not the docker internal one.**

In the previous docker versions, **I can change the hostname by assign env variable HOSTNAME, this will change the hostname correspondingly. But now, with docker version 1.12. This kind of linux action doesn't work in that linux behavior.**

So if compose like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  test:
    build: .
    extra_hosts:
        thisservice: "192.168.1.7"
    environment:
      - HOSTNAME=thisservice
    image: dockerv1.12-test
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
CMD sleep 120
```

Go inside the docker container by `docker-compose exec test sh`, then `cat /etc/hosts` looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
192.168.1.7 thisservice
172.28.0.2  80260fa6667f
```

While:

```
$ hostname
80260fa6667f

$ echo $HOSTNAME
thisservice
```

**This is the wrong behavior as I mentioned above, and things like this did not happen with previous docker version.**

In this case, the service in the container will have no idea about the IP I assigned but go for the docker internal IP. This is not what I want. And not correct behavior in my opinion.

I tried on both Ubuntu 16.04 and Centos 7.2; Before I upgrade docker v1.10, both distro worked as expected. Both went 'wrong' after upgrade docker to v1.12.1 and v1.12.3.

So is this a bug or on purpose for swarm mode within docker v1.12?

And how could I change the hostname as I need?

Answer (score 4):

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  test:
    build: .
    hostname: thisservice
    image: dockerv1.12-tes
```

Comment: yep, this works. But still not same behavior as docker version 1.10.

This is my bad, I did not describe the issue correctly. I will update the main question above.

Comment: Your example works as you expected in my docker 1.12.3 with docker-compose 1.7.0. Instead of setting HOSTNAME env variable you can use directly hostname in  extra_hosts:
     - "thisservice:192.168.1.7"

Comment: I tried docker v1.12.3 + docker-compose 1.8.1. still same as I described above. I am guessing is the command of hostname are different from command of "echo $HOSTNAME".  My services have to use hostname and the IP I need to register service on zookeeper cluster. So I have to use an env variable HOSTNAME.